# Angularjs directive, call same directive from within itself

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building generic angularjs directive to support editing of json object. I have json data and also admin data to have details about original data. Following code details which I am using to build my generic directive.
Please refer [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x2lqHjYq48gwxW7oYyEQ?p=preview) for running code.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/x2lqHjYq48gwxW7oYyEQ?p=preview
Directive Code:
app.directive("objecteditor", [function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "ObjectEditor.html",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                object: '=',
                objectAdmin: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                //Method to initialize 
                scope.init = function () {

                };
                //Call init() to initialze the loading.
                scope.init();                
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Directive Template:

```
<div>
  <h4 data-ng-bind-template="{{objectAdmin.displayName}}"></h4>
  <div data-ng-repeat="column in objectAdmin.objectDefinition">
    <div data-ng-switch="column.type">
      <div data-ng-switch-when="string">
        <label class="label-plain" data-ng-bind-template="{{column.displayName}}"></label>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="object[objectAdmin.name][column.name]" placeholder="{{displayName}}" title="{{displayName}}" name="textBox{{name}}" required />
      </div>
      <!--Call same object for child type as object. But how??? If i call <object> directive here then goes into infinite cycle -->
      <div data-ng-switch-when="object">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller Code:

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('ApplicationController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    //Method to initialize 
    $scope.init = function() {
      //Set json data strucutre for editing 
      $scope.objectAdmin ={"name":"bankinfo","displayName":"Bank Info","type":"object","objectDefinition":[{"name":"name","displayName":"Bank Name","type":"string"},{"name":"mainPhone","displayName":"Main Phone","type":"string"},{"name":"contact","displayName":"Contact","type":"object","objectDefinition":[{"name":"name","displayName":"Name","type":"string"},{"name":"title","displayName":"Title","type":"string"}]}]};
      $scope.object={"bankinfo":{"name":"Chase Bank - Newburgh","mainPhone":"1 (845) 333-3333","contact":{"name":"Donna Shuler","title":"Commercial Accounts Mgr."}}};
    };

    //Call init() to initialze the loading.
    $scope.init();
  }
]);
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="ObjectEditor.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body data-ng-controller="ApplicationController">
<h2>How to call same directive within itself?</h2>
 <!--Use object editor directive to edit the object details -->
 <objecteditor data-object="object" data-object-admin="objectAdmin"></objecteditor>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to make my directive generic so that same type of object editing can be supported by single directive.

When I tried to call same directive within itself then it fall into infinite loop (which is expected).

How can I achieve this functionality in directive?
Please help.

Comment: Please put the relevant parts of the code in the question itself - don't rely on a link. Instead, you mostly have a JSON structure here (which, btw, could be further simplified for illustrative purposes)

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking...

Comment: Where are there any children in the first place? Try using an `ng-if` then pass children to your directive html

Comment: I am trying to build the directives in which markup is generated based on the input data, my input data is very much generic and it has child of itself. I want to call same directive from itself

Comment: @joy do you want to call recursively?

Comment: yes, I want to call recursive from same directive template.

Comment: If you see the my HTML markup is driven by the data modal and I call it "objectAdmin" i.e. this is to edit the object. Since json object can have child has other json object as well therefore I want to call same template to avoid writing same code again and again.

Comment: You can refer http://plnkr.co/edit/x2lqHjYq48gwxW7oYyEQ?p=preview to see the running code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going through the recursive directive and came across following post which was helpful to implement my requirement. 
https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/recursive-directives. Following is code to implement this.
Object Editor Directive Template:

```
<div>
    <objecttree data-object="object" data-object-admin="objectAdmin" data-folder-guid="folderGuid" data-hide-header="'true'"></objecttree>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="objectTree">
    <div class="clear-left">
        <h4 data-ng-if="!hideHeader" data-ng-bind-template="{{objectAdmin.displayName}}"></h4>
        <div data-ng-repeat="column in objectAdmin.objectDefinition">
            <div data-ng-switch="column.type">            
                <imageeditor data-ng-switch-when="image" data-image="object[column.name]" data-folder-guid="folderGuid" data-column="column"></imageeditor>
                <formcheckbox data-ng-switch-when="boolean" data-input-value="object[column.name]" data-editable="column.editable" data-name="column.name" data-display-name="column.displayName" data-formName="'resourceAddEditFormName'"></formcheckbox>                                      
                <addresseditor data-ng-switch-when="address" data-address="object[column.name]" data-column="column" data-collection-admin="objectAdmin"></addresseditor>                        
                <formtextbox data-ng-switch-when="string" data-ng-if="!column.isDropdown" data-input-value="object[column.name]" data-editable="column.editable" data-name="column.name" data-display-name="column.displayName" data-formName="'resourceAddEditFormName'"></formtextbox>
                <dropdownbox data-ng-switch-when="string" data-ng-if="column.isDropdown" class="admin-textbox" data-selected-id-list="object[column.name]" data-dropdown="column" data-multiple="column.dropdownTypeMultiple"></dropdownbox>            
                <div data-ng-switch-when="object">
                    <hr/>                    
                    <objecttree data-object="object[column.name]" data-object-admin="column" data-folder-guid="folderGuid" data-hide-header="'true'"></objecttree>
                </div> 
                <div data-ng-switch-when="array">
                    <hr/>                    
                    <arrayobjecttree data-objects="object[column.name]" data-objects-admin="column" data-folder-guid="folderGuid" data-hide-header="'true'"></arrayobjecttree>
                </div>                 
            </div>        
        </div>    
    </div>    
    </script>    
</div>
```

Object Tree:

```
app.directive("objecttree", ['$compile', '$templateCache', function ($compile, $templateCache) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                object: '=',
                objectAdmin: '=',
                folderGuid: '=',
                hideHeader: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.replaceWith(
                        $compile(
                                $templateCache.get('objectTree')
                                )(scope)
                        );

            }
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is Shankar. You can use the below solution for recursive directive.
Please confirm me whether this resolves your issue.If not, you can let me know.
As I'm not able to paste my entire code here, you can  find the solution in my Github repository:(i.e. gmssankar/myRepository/Recursive Directive)

https://github.com/gmssankar/myRepository/blob/master/Recursive%20Directive

The code can be found in the following link too in plunker:
plnkr.co/edit/WrZekRS5AzfFJhQ2d3XK?p=preview

I'm not able to   attach the complete code here as it restricts the number of lines. The logic is: Inside Directive template display bank name, main phone,contact name and contact title from the passed object. Then check if the passed object, has object definition (i.e child nodes). If yes, then extract each child using ng-repeat , and pass to same directive. Issue gets resolved here. From Github or plnkr , you can access the complete code.

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your answer here, please? It makes no sense to add a link to a github repository which might become deleted

Comment: Hi, the custom directive's template can be changed as below: